# How do I deserlize a cypress JSON request

Tags: json, deserialization, cypress

I am trying to assert on the response body. However, I get the following response:

`{\r\n  "physicalID": "Physical file updated",\r\n  "fileData": null,\r\n }`

I would like to deserialize it and assert on a JSON object

Comment: `JSON.parse` it?

Comment: I have tried that 

let body = JSON.parse(response.body);
expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
expect(response).to.have.property('body')
cy.log(body)
expect(response.body).to.eq( { "ID" : null , "timeline" : null })

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question related to Cypress itself, the response you are getting is not a valid JSON string so you are unable to parse the response and assert on it. The only thing i could assist with is how to parse this particular string, you can however get a totally different string as a response from another endpoint. for now, considering this was the string you needed to parse to assert on :

```
// Remove \r\n
let x = '{\r\n  "physicalID": "Physical file updated",\r\n  "fileData": null,\r\n }'
x= x.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, ""); // "{  "physicalID": "Physical file updated",  "fileData": null, }"

//Remove the last ',' 
x = x.slice(0,x.lastIndexOf(',')) + x.slice(x.lastIndexOf(',')+1) //"{  "physicalID": "Physical file updated",  "fileData": null }"

// Now parse it
x = JSON.parse(x);
```